# BlueZ, How to turn off br/edr without using btmgmt?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm new to Bluetooth and BlueZ, I was working on a BLE project using BlueZ, for some reason I cannot use `btmgmt -i hci0 bredr off` command to turn off br/edr. I was wondering how to turn of br/edr using hcitool or any other util provided by BlueZ. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days reading some question on Stackoverflow and reading Bluetooth specification. I finally found a way to use hcitool to do it. The command is

`hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 12 02 01 04 02 0A 0C 0B`

where 01 04 is the key 01 referred to the flag, 04 referred to bredr not supported. Thank u all.